# One or more plugins require a higher Android SDK version error

Tags: flutter

One or more plugins require a higher Android SDK version.
Fix this issue by adding the following to D:\Flutter Projets\scheduler\android\app\build.gradle:
android {
compileSdkVersion 33
...
}

2

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Users\lijoj\Documents\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1156
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\Users\lijoj\Documents\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 1):

Go into the Android -> App -> build.gradle and set `targetSdkVersion` and `compileSdkVersion` to 33

Because You have used many plugins in your project and one of them is latest plugin, so latest plugin requires latest Android sdk platfrom.

Comment: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Answer (score 1):

In your IDE open folder android/app/build.gradle and search for compileSdkVersion(usually inside android attribute) and in from of that replace 'flutter.compileSdkVersion' with '33'.

Comment: Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

Comment: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.